# Iterating through array of objects to group all data by date

Tags: angularjs

I have my json file as below:

```
{
  "components":{
  "record1":
  [
    {
    "date":1619038000,
    "name":"Susan",
    "status":"true"
  },
  {
    "date":1419038000,
    "name":"Vinay",
    "status":"false"
  },
  {
    "date":1419038000,
    "name":"Ajay",
    "status":"true"
  }
  ],
  "record2":[
    {
    "date":1419037000,
    "name":"Soumya",
    "status":"false"
  },
  {
    "date":1619038000,
    "name":"Savio",
    "status":"true"
  },
  {
    "date":1326439320,
    "name":"Thereza",
    "status":"false"
  }
  ]
}
}
```

This is my js file:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

 app.controller("Control",function($scope,$http){
   $http.get('myData.json').
       success(function(data){
                  $scope.tableData = data.components;
                });
});
```

I want to group data from both arrays and display them in such a way that data having similar dates are grouped together. Maybe if I have more record inside then how wud I do it.Please do help me in this. I want to group them as follows:

```
date       name   status 17th april Susan  true
           Soumya false 19th april Vinay  false
           Ajay   true 20th april Thereza false
```

Comment: You are saying "both arrays" but you have shown a single one. Also, you said you want to group them, but did not say how. Sample inputs and desirable outputs are desirable.

Comment: here record1 is one array and record2 is another array

Comment: Thank you, I have edited your question as well to make it more readable and written an answer as well.

Comment: How would I use it in my html to display it in the way I showed in the question at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I understood the question well, but this is how you can gather elements having the same date:

```
function group(inputs, groupClause) {
    var g = {};
    for (var key in inputs) {
        for (var innerKey in inputs[key]) {
            if (inputs[key][innerKey]) {
                if (!g[inputs[key][innerKey][groupClause]]) g[inputs[key][innerKey][groupClause]] = [];
                g[inputs[key][innerKey][groupClause]].push(inputs[key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return g;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
var myGroup = group([myobject["components"]["record1"], myobject["components"]], "date");
```

If you do not know in advance how many records will be, then you can do something like this:

```
var input = [];
var index = 1;
while (myobject["components"]["record" + index]) {
    input.push(myobject["components"]["record" + index]);
    index++;
}
var myGroup = group(input, "date");
```

Comment: How would I use it in my html to display it in the way I showed in the question at the end

Comment: That's a different question, If this one solves the question, then you might consider accepting it and ask a separate question where you specify what you want in your HTML, which is unclear in this context. But to give you a hint, you can use table and inside tr items where each group would represent a row and you could separate group items with <br>

Comment: yes ok, i would post my question in a better way..Thanks

Comment: @Susanna there is nothing wrong with your question. It is okay. The fact that it is answerable proves that it isa decent question. However, this site is a question-answer site and a question should be an understandable and solvable question. If we complicate our current conversation with things which were originally outside the question, then the quality of this conversation will suffer. Therefore I suggested that you could accept this answer as the answer of your current question, ask a separate one about your HTML issue and let me know about it.

Comment: @Susanna this only applies if this answer solves your problem of grouping items based on date. If it is not adequate for you, then please let me know about it. However, users are more motivated to answer your questions if you are willing to accept an answer when it proves to be correct. Asking a further question instead of accepting a correct answer will not really motivate users to help you.

Comment: Hi...This logic helps to group by date but the requirement to my answer is more clear to me now so I have asked the question again separately..Could you please look into that

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at  [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby) , You add that and you get a bunch of filters which includes `groupBy` too which can group contents of an array according to the index you specify .

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [lodash groupby](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy). Let's say the object is stored in variable called `obj`. Then you can:

```
var arr = obj.components.record1.concat(obj.components.record2);
var a = _.groupBy(arr, function(n) {
    return n.date;
});
```

Running this code with the object given in the question, will give something like:

```
Object { 1326439320: Array[1], 1419037000: Array[1], 1419038000: Array[2], 1619038000: Array[2] }
```

If you want to loop through one of the groups, just select it bey key:

```
a["1419038000"].forEach(x => console.log(x))
```

which will produce:

> Object { date: 1419038000, name: "Vinay", status: "false" }
>   Object {
>   date: 1419038000, name: "Ajay", status: "true" }

Comment: ok,thanks..but what if I had a number of record arrays inside..how could i loop through them

Comment: @Soumya, please see if the updated answer is more helpful.